# Is "the sin of the world" a type of sin? John 1v29 " Behold the Lamb of the world which taketh away the sin of the world"? A.V

Tags: word-study

Sins which belong to this world have the possibility of being taken away. But in Luke 10:18 we read "And he said to them, I beheld Satan as lightning fall from heaven". I understand that Satan was cast out of heaven because of his sin.

Is there then a sin not belonging to this world? A heavenly sin for which there is no redemption. Are there different types of sin and worldly sin or "sin of the world" one of them?
"For if God did not spare angels when they sinned". 2 Peter 2v4. I can see no reason to assume that the sins of these angels might be worldly ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bible never discusses "heavenly sin" so whether Christ provided the possibility for sinful angels and Satan to be redeemed is a completely moot point.  Therefore, I will NOT discuss it here.  The closest we get is the final destiny of Satan as described symbolically in places like Rev 20:1-3, 7-10.

What the Bible does discuss, and at some considerable length, is the sin of the world, that is the collective sin of all of us individually John 1:29, 3:16, 16:9, Matt 18:7, Rom 5:12, 13, 1 Cor 5:10, 8:13, Gal 3:22, Eph 2:2, Phil 2:15, Heb 9:26, 10:5, 2 Peter 2:20, etc.  Sin is simply sin - separation from God and the Bible's focus is our salvation.

The closest the Bible comes to classifying sin is in 1 John 2:15, 16 where the sins or love of the world is described as, "the lust of the flesh, the lust of the eyes, and the pride of life".  This certainly covers everything about our human sinfulness.

In all these places, Jesus is the solution to the world's sin problem by providing atonement for sin John 1:29, 12:32, Rom 3:23, 24, 5:8, 10, 15, 18, 11:32, 2 Cor 5:14, 18, 19, 1 Tim 2:6, Titus 2:11, Heb 2:9, 1 John 2:2, Isa 53:6, etc.

Comment: @ Mac's Musings evil in the heavenlies Eph 6v12 under the rulers of Eph 3v10 have been put to open shame Col 2v15. Is that not evil/sin which is not of this world. i.e. worldly?

Comment: Col 2:15 does no say what the authorities are (although it is possibly implied).  However, Eph 3:10 & 6:12 definitely discuss heavenly places but not heavenly sin.  Eph 3:10 should be read in conjunction with 1 Peter 1:12 about angels.  Eph 6:12 is the only place that discusses wickedness in heaven - a reference to Satan and his cohorts as per Eph 2:2.

Comment: @Mac'sMusings: "World," as it is used in 1 John 2 is the Gk. cosmos. Think of the cosmos as the world order under Satan's authority and his domain (see Jesus's temptation, in which Satan offers Jesus all the kingdoms of this world). The lust of the eyes and the flesh, and the pride of life are the default settings of Satan's world system. The only escape available to God's image-bearers is the cross of Christ and the blood he shed there. His blood has the cleansing power to forgive and cleanse us of our sins.The destruction of Satan's world system is assured by Christ's death & resurrection.

Comment: The victory parade Paul mentions in 2 Cor 2:14 and the leading of captivity captive in Eph 4:7-8 are the same thing. Through Christ's cross-death and subsequent resurrection, he leads us in victory experientially and make's a display of the defeated captives of his captivity. We Christ followers enact that defeat as we exercise the spiritual gifts he has given to us as the spoils of his war against Satan.We are already set free from the penalty of sin, but our battle against the power of sin continues until God takes us home. When he does, we will then be free from the presence of sin.

Comment: I fully agree.  The victory parade (2 Cor 2:14) is a parade (in metaphorical terms) of saved people before the observers, who are not defined, except perhaps in a similar statement in 1 Cor 4:9 where the spectators are said to be, "the world, both to angels and to men."  But this does not discuss sin, nor heavenly sin.

Answer (score 0):

John 1:29. NT Jonathan Mitchell

The next day (or: On the morrow) he is looking at and observing Jesus [= Yahshua] progressively coming toward him, and he begins saying, "Look! (Pay attention, see and perceive)! God’s Lamb (or: the Lamb from God; the Lamb having the character and qualities of God; or, in apposition: the Lamb which is God), the One continuously lifting up and progressively carrying away the Sin of the world, and removing the sin which belongs to and is a part of the System (or: habitually picking up and taking away the failure and error brought on by the organized system; progressively removing the falling short and the missing of the goal from the world of culture, religion, economy and government, society, and from the aggregate of humanity)!

John 1.29 Mirror Study Bible

The next day John saw Jesus approaching him, and declared: “Behold the Lamb of God; this is the one who would 1lift the sin of the 2cosmos like an anchor from the sea floor, for mankind to sail free!” (This is unheard of! It is not about a revengeful god demanding a sacrifice; this is your Father and Creator providing himself as sacrifice. The ultimate sacrifice for sins would never be something we did, or brought to God to appeal to him; the shocking scandal of the cross, is the fact that mankind is confronted with the extravagant, embarrassing proportions of the love of their Maker; Father Son and Spirit would go to the most ridiculous extreme to finally convince us of their heart towards us! In order to persuade us of our worth, God speaks the most severe scapegoat language: “Behold the Lamb of God, who takes away [airo - lifts up] the sins of the world!” This completely disarms religion! Suddenly there is nothing that we can do to persuade God about our sincere intentions; this is God persuading us of their eternal love dream! The word αἴρω - 1airo, a primary verb; to lift up; by implication to take up or away; specifically to raise the anchor to sail away. See John 12:32 When I am lifted up from the earth, I will draw all judgment to me! Also John 19:15 - Lift him up! Lift him up! Crucify him!” The word, 2kosmos in the NT refers to the entire human family and their social structures.)